# Consistent User load Hitting the application server failed after 500 threads

Tags: jmeter

I was running a 500 user load for 1 hr in JMeter. The user load is going to 500 . But after some few minutes its comming down to 150-200 users.The RAM is 3GB and processor is Core 2 Duo.How to resolve this.

Comment: Please add more detail. Also, this question may be better suited to http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: Are you getting the user load from the server, or from Jmeter?  Also, what are you seeing as results in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

The number of threads running on a machine depends on the Heap memory defined in jmeter file on Linux and jmeter.bat file on windows.
Check for HEAP variable and increase the heap memory. If you have 2 GB memory increase the -Xms and -Xmx to 1536m. 
The actual problem lies with the Heap memory where threads are not getting memory to be allocated.